# WP Theme Customizer - options order

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i've got a problem with theme customizer. My code is:

```
function candyfloss_theme_customizer( $wp_customize ) { 
    class Heading extends WP_Customize_Control {
    public $type = 'heading';

    public function render_content() {
        ?>
        <label>
        <span class="customize-control-title" style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #666;"><strong><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></strong></span>            
        </label>
        <?php
    }
}
$wp_customize->add_setting('products_heading', array(
    'default',
) );
$wp_customize->add_control(new Heading ($wp_customize, 'products_heading', array(
    'label' => __('Home - products section'),
    'type' => 'heading',
    'section' => 'home',        
) ) );

$wp_customize->add_setting('candyfloss_product_first', array(
    'deafault',
) );
$wp_customize->add_control('candyfloss_product_first', array(
    'label' => __('First product page'),
    'type' => 'dropdown-pages',
    'section' => 'home',        
) );
$wp_customize->add_setting('candyfloss_product_second', array(
    'deafault',
) );
$wp_customize->add_control('candyfloss_product_second', array(
    'label' => __('Second product page'),
    'type' => 'dropdown-pages',
    'section' => 'home',
) );
$wp_customize->add_setting('candyfloss_product_third', array(
    'deafault',
) );
$wp_customize->add_control('candyfloss_product_third', array(
    'label' => __('Third product page'),
    'type' => 'dropdown-pages',
    'section' => 'home',
) );

};
add_action( 'customize_register', 'candyfloss_theme_customizer', 11 );
```

And the problem is in order of this. At admin panel view is

second option,
first option,
heading,
third option,

Can anyone know, what I'm doing wrong? Could You help me? I'll be thankful

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer. Wordpress gives a random priority to controls. To solve it we just need to add priority number to each control.

eg.:

```
$wp_customize->add_control(new Heading ($wp_customize, 'products_heading', array(
    'label' => __('Home - products section'),
    'type' => 'heading',
    'section' => 'home',
    'priority' => 2,        
) ) );
```